# Replace all leading "/" with "", through regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all leading "/" in a string with "", using a regular expression.

Eg:

```
var input="//////x";
// replace 
var output = "x";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code

```
 someString.replace(/\//g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str="//////x" ;
str1=str.replace(/\//g,"");
alert("Input="+str+"  Output="+str1);
```